# Set dependency name in build/intermediates/exploded-aar/

Tags: android, maven, android-studio, gradle

When I import dependencies from Maven, which have name like `aaa.bbb.ccc:library.1.2.3`, Gradle creates a folders such as `aaa.bbb.ccc/library` in `app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar` folder. So, I have some of this libs and Android Studio detects them as same libraries and I can not run project. How I can solve this?

Comment: Are they the same libs?

Comment: @user3623735 They are different libs, but they have same end in name. For example, "com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4" and "com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1@aar"